# Why does spring resolve views only when one level url path present on controller request mapping annotation

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am implementing a website with Spring MVC and I've noticed the following problem. I have a controller like this one

```
/**
 * Created by adelin.ghanayem@cayetanogaming.com on 4/7/15.
 */
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class UserControlPanelController {

    // this url has a second level. /user/panel
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/panel",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @Secured(value = {"ROLE_USER"})
    public ModelAndView mainPage(){
         return new ModelAndView("user-panel.jsp");
    }
}
```

The view user-panel.jsp is not resolver I receive

```
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /myapp/user/login-user.jsp. Reason:

    /myapp/user/login-user.jsp
```

However, when I map the method to `@RequestMapping(value = "/user",method = RequestMethod.GET)`

The view is resolved. The jsp page is placed at the root of the webapp (web directory )

Now when I tried to map the method to `@RequestMapping(value = "/user/panel",method = RequestMethod.GET)` and `return new ModelAndView("/user-panel.jsp");` NOTE THE ROOT SLASH. The view resolved properly.

Comment: How is your `ViewResolver` configured? Generally you should only be returning `user-panel` and let the `ViewResolver` care about the rest...

Comment: You need to post your ViewResolver configuration

Comment: I don't I've configured one anywhere so I guess it is the default one

Comment: Share your jsp code from which you are calling this method.

Comment: I am calling it from my browser URL ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a view resolver in your configuration so spring knows where to look for the views.  If you do not provide one, you must specify the path to the file, which is why the "user-panel.jsp" does not work, but the "/user-panel.jsp" does work.